# python yaml save and load a nested class

Tags: python, yaml

I have a nested class:

```py
# hello.py
import pydantic as dan

class Hello:
    @dan.dataclasses.dataclass
    class Data:
        data_a: int

import yaml
data = Hello.Data(1)
filename = "hi.yaml"

with open(filename, "w") as fh:
    yaml.dump(data, fh)

with open(filename, "r") as fh:
    yaml.load(fh, yaml.Loader) # Causes the error
```

It seems the dumper doesn't recognize that the `Data` is defined inside `Hello` and saves the class as `python/object:hello.Data`. I expected `python/object:hello.Hello.Data`.

Is there a workaround for this?

I have a nested class because I have multiple classes that requires a dedicated `dataclass` for each.

I found [this](https://smarie.github.io/python-yamlable/generated/gallery/1_basic_usage_demo/) library. It will be painful for me to add the decorator for each class. But I will try it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'ruamel.yaml' instead of 'pyyaml'. 'pyyaml' has a few limitations in handling nested objects.

Pip Install:

```
pip install ruamel.yaml
```

Code

```
# hello.py
import pydantic as dan

class Hello:
    @dan.dataclasses.dataclass
    class Data:
        data_a: int

from ruamel import yaml

data = Hello.Data(1)
filename = "hi.yaml"

with open(filename, "w") as fh:
    yaml.dump(data, fh)

with open(filename, "r") as fh:
    yaml.load(fh, yaml.Loader)  # Causes the error
```

Comment: As a beginner in `yaml`, this worked like a charm without changing my code.

Answer (score 1):

- pydantic generates a separate `dataclass` for each nested class, which can cause the YAML dumper to save the class as `python/object:hello.Data` instead of `python/object:hello.Hello.Data`
- define a custom `YAML representer` funct that represents instances of `Hello.Data` as `python/object:hello.Hello.Data` and then register this `representer` using `yaml.add_representer` `before` dumping the data to YAML.

```py
def hello_data_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_mapping('python/object:hello.Hello.Data', dan.asdict(data))

yaml.add_representer(Hello.Data, hello_data_representer)
```